# Minimum Detectable Effect Size for multiple linear regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, effect-size

I am trying to calculate the minimum detectable effect size (MDE) of an explanatory variable in a multiple linear regression.

The regression looks like the following:
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2*X_2 + \beta_3*X_3 + \beta_4*X_4 + \epsilon_i
$$
whereby I am only interested in the MDE of $X_1$ in this multiple linear regression.

I have found code for linear regression in R: pwr.f2.test().

However, I am not sure if this can eliminate the minimum detectable effect size for one variable. Does anyone know how to get the minimum detectable effect size of one explanatory variable in a multiple linear regression? How can I implement this in R?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a useful formula to remember:

$$\pm \beta_{j}^{a}=\frac{\left(z_{1-\alpha / 2}+z_{\gamma}\right) \sigma_{y \mid \mathbf{x}}}{\sigma_{x_{j}} \sqrt{n\left(1-\rho_{j}^{2}\right)}}$$

Here, $\beta_j^\alpha$ is the minimal detectable effect for a covariate assuming:

- Our FPR is $\alpha$ and our desired power is $\gamma$.  If you use the popular $\alpha=0.05$ and $\gamma=0.8$ then $z_{a-\alpha/2} \approx 1.96$ and $z_\gamma \approx 0.84$.
- The residual variation is $\sigma_{y\vert x}$.  This is akin to the standard deviation of the residuals assuming the linear model is the true model.
- The standard deviation of the covariate is $\sigma_{x_j}$.  If the covariate is continuous, this can always be rescaled to 1 through standardization.  If the covariate is binary then you can use $\sigma_{x_j} = \sqrt{f(1-f)}$ where $f$ is the fraction of your sample with the covariate set to 1.
- $n$ is the sample size
- $1/(1-\rho_j^2)$ is the variance inflation factor for the covariate (which can be hard to estimate a priori).

Comment: Can you maybe cite a paper or explain where this formula comes from?

Comment: @Laura Sure.  Formulas come from the end of chapter 4 of [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461413523) book.  Citations and explanations are included therein.

Comment: Thank you! Do you by any chance also know if there is a way to implement it in R (despite calculating the MDE by hand)?

Comment: @Laura it should be very easy to program yourself, I don't know of any functions or libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Demetri's answer, the approach greatly simplifies finding MDE in a multivariate model - a point of confusion for many early analysts. The $\sigma_{y|x}$  that is expressed is conditional on *all the other x*. In other words, there is practically no difference between finding power in a multivariate model and in a bivariate model: inference for the model coefficient boils down to knowing the conditional variance of the Y, and subtracting off all the degrees of freedom for adjusting the other $X$; it is just a t-test.

So proceed by considering MDE for a t-test, supply the conditional variance of $Y$ adjusting all the other covariates which is required as a free-parameter in the power/sample size calculations, then subtract 1 from the overall $n$ for each adjusted variable.